# Are there any special considerations on a business trip to Shanghai?

Tags: china, culture

For a German on a trip to Shanghai, are there some surprising business rules which could lead to some kind of embarrassing situation? Is there something which would be considered especially rude by a Chinese engineer, if his German co-worker does it?

Answer (score 3):

Wikitravel has an (understandably) [massive article on China](http://wikitravel.org/en/China).

However the two sections that may interest you are:

[Understand - People and Habits](http://wikitravel.org/en/China#People_and_Habits) - why people do or don't do certain things in China

[Respect](http://wikitravel.org/en/China#Respect) - how to avoid faux pas in China

When in doubt, be conservative, polite, and follow the lead of your hosts.